# Any idea how website capture google search keywords in in their title/url dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript, search, seo

To be more specific let me give an example : If I search a keyword "rankog" on google I get the website rankog.com in the search result, but in the google search results i find some results like (a)www.markosweb.com/www/rankog.com/ and (b)www.tracedomain.com/rankog.com, I know these are some seo tools which give domain information.

My question in 1 line is how such websites (a and b) capture the search terms in their title/url?.

If I want to do the same thing - Capture a search term in google on the title/url of my page how should I do it; say I have 1000 keywords and I want to capture them in my page url, as done in (a) and (b) making 1000 pages is not the solution i guess. How do these website work and capture 1000's of keyword in their url, title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done by parsing the referrer URL.  Most browsers will send the prior URL in their header.  You can parse this, and figure out what the search terms were.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Now, getting your page indexed by Google is a whole 'nother story.  You can sniff for their user-agent and dynamically create a bunch of fake pages, but if you do that, everyone will hate you and won't spend much time on your sites anyway.

If you want your site to show up in Google listings, the best way to do that is to have great content that others will link to.

Comment: from what I know $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] comes into play when one clicks on the webpage, and we can capture information of the referring page. But my question is different: When I search a term say "abcd.com" on google the results show the pages related to abcd.com then there are few other google results like www.example.com/abcd.com (please see the example I given in the question). here $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] does not come in to play because we have not clicked on any google result or does it? I am not very clear - could you please elaborate, thanks a lot.

Comment: @yuvraj, You are misunderstanding.  There are two issues here.  The first is that you need to know what was search from on Google when Google links to your page.  For that, you read the referrer URL.  The second issue is getting Google to index your pages, as if they had those search times, in the first place.  To do that, you need to have some sort of index file that then links to all of your inner pages with appropriate search terms.  Since you are obviously not going to create thousands of inner pages, you can simply use a friendly URL to determine the search terms.

Comment: Bang on target "The second issue is getting Google to index your pages, as if they had those search times, in the first place. To do that, you need to have some sort of index file that then links to all of your inner pages with appropriate search terms. Since you are obviously not going to create thousands of inner pages, you can simply use a friendly URL to determine the search terms." ....... Can you please elaborate on this or give me some links from where I learn to do it .... this is exactly what I am looking for and I am unable to find a solution.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the above point, thanks a lot in advance :)